# IE7 web layout problem/older Firefox layout problems

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, layout, cross-browser, jquery-tabs

I am working on this site http://gitastudents.com/~hattrupn/final/site/index-f.html
there seems to be an error with older versions of ie with the tabs staying black until you scroll back over them when they should be blue unless they are on that specific tab. Also on older versions of firefox when you click on directions the iframe messes up the tabs when you click a different tab and pushes them to the right. Would really appreciate anyone who could help fix this or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging layout issues in older browsers can be tricky business. I usually start by making sure that all tags close correctly and no quotes are left open. Next I look for conflicting styles like a combination of width and padding wont work right in ie6. Having the correct Doctype is also important. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3a%2f%2fgitastudents.com%2f%7ehattrupn%2ffinal%2fsite%2findex-f.html

your iframes dont validate

use the inspect element console in chrome you have nearly 70 Unsafe JavaScript attempts to access frames